# Bigquery Time as duration, convert to second

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have a problem with time from string

overall, my goal is want to get how many seconds from duration AS string that containing HH:MM:SS

```
00:01:00 -> 60
00:02:30 -> 150
01:00:00 -> 3600
```

my query is like this

```
TIME_DIFF(CAST(duration AS TIME), '00:00:00', SECOND)
```

However, query above does not work with duration that more than 24:00:00
is there any different solution to get

Comment: What is the data type of your original column?

Comment: provide example of data that has duration more than 24 hours? is it something like `36:00:00`? or something else? it is not clear from your question

Answer (score 1):

I assume the duration column is a string representing time in following format `HHHH:MM:SS` where HHHH can be any value of hours even above 24. If this is a case  - consider below solution

```
select duration, 
  3600 * cast(regexp_extract(duration, r'^\d*') as int64) +
  time_diff(cast(regexp_replace(duration, r'^\d*', '00') as time), '00:00:00', second) as seconds
from `project.dataset.table`
```

below is example of output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split "time" values longer than 24 hours, then I must assume that your source data is a string and not a `time`.  In BigQuery, time values must be less than 24 hours.

So, use string operations:

```
select (cast(split(hhmmss, ':')[ordinal(1)] as int64) * 60 * 60 +
        cast(split(hhmmss, ':')[ordinal(2)] as int64) * 60 +
        cast(split(hhmmss, ':')[ordinal(3)] as int64)
       ) as seconds
from (select '00:01:00' as hhmmss union all 
      select '00:02:30' union all 
      select '01:00:00') x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out an alternative way to parse TIMESTAMP DATA:-

```sql
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT '2019-05-03T00:01:00' AS F_DATE 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-05-03T00:02:30'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-05-03T01:00:30'
)
select F_DATE, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST( F_DATE AS TIMESTAMP))  * 60 *60 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(F_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CAST(F_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)) AS DATE_SEC FROM DATA
```